# salvagewallet is not in the Bitcoin Core Console

Tags: bitcoin-core, command-line-options

I want to try the `-salvagewallet` command, but it is not in the console. What is the command line syntax?

Answer (score 3):

`-salvagewallet` is not a command that is run from the debug console. It is not one of Bitcoin Core's RPC calls. Rather `-salvagewallet` is a command line option. You set it in the command that is used to run Bitcoin Core or you set it in the bitcoin.conf file by adding `salvagewallet=1` to the bitcoin.conf file and then starting Bitcoin Core.

Note that `-salvagewallet` does not always work and sometimes may result in corruption of your wallet if it is not already corrupted. It is only as a last resort option. You should always make a backup of your wallet file prior to starting Bitcoin Core with `-salvagewallet`.

Comment: It has been suggested to rename it to `-savagewallet`.